# Guest Additions in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm setting up a development server with VirtualBox.  I've installed Ubuntu 10.10 Server. I want to use filesharing to setup the files that I need to develop on but it seems that the CD drive is not mounting to install the Virtualbox guest additions. How can I configure this to setup the file sharing.

Comment: If you want help with the CD mounting part (which you don't need here), you need to tell us what you tried and what happened when you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Ubuntu in a VirtualBox VM, you can install the guest additions as an Ubuntu package. Either grab [virtualbox-guest-additions](http://packages.ubuntu.com/virtualbox-guest-additions) [Install virtualbox-guest-additions http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/virtualbox-guest-additions) or [virtualbox-ose-guest-utils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/virtualbox-ose-guest-utils) [Install virtualbox-ose-guest-utils http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/virtualbox-ose-guest-utils) and [virtualbox-ose-guest-x11](http://packages.ubuntu.com/virtualbox-ose-guest-x11) [Install virtualbox-ose-guest-x11 http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/virtualbox-ose-guest-x11). The OSE guest utilities are compatible with the proprietary VM and vice versa (at least with respect to common features such as file sharing and pointer grabbing).